New Hair Curves System: Rigging with Auto Rig Pro
I've created hair with the new Curves hair system.  I've also rigged my character.  How to I rig the hair to get it to follow the head positions?  The hair doesn't need to move separately.  It can follow the head turns in my imported MOCAP.

If you have added the hair directly to the head, the hair should automatically follow the head if the Armature modifier is above the Geometry Nodes "Surface Deform" modifier. If you have used a hair cap/an additional mesh object for the hair, you must weight-paint it like the head.
